# Linux from Scratch - EFI variables are not supported on this system

Tags: linux, uefi, reboot

Linux from Scratch 11.1, non system-d edition, is the book I am following. I followed a guide from someone named Kernotex. I followed his video on how to dual boot LFS on a machine with Windows. So I am at Chapter 10.4, where he is setting up grub with a command that isn't the same as the one on the book. And it shows me an error.

The command I ran: `grub-install --bootloader-id=LFS --recheck --debug & grub-log`

For all the details, you can find the log here: https://pastebin.com/SVX0iW7x

The main error for those of you who don't want to go through the logs: `EFI variables are not supported on this system.`

Also, if I have to reboot, then please show me a guide, or please help me through the process.

EDIT: This is running on a Debian 11 Live system on a 8GB USB Drive.

Comment: Are you booting Windows in EFI mode or BIOS aka. CSM aka. legacy mode? Is your disk partitioned as MBR or GPT?

Comment: I am booting in Windows 11, which means that I should have UEFI and GPT on my system. There is no option for UEFI, and switching to MBR (I'm assuming) will format my system.

Comment: That's correct. This error message hints that you may have booted Debian using CSM. In that case OS won't have access to the EFI stuff. Try to disable CSM in UEFI setup - you're booting Windows in EFI mode, so it shouldn't do any harm. Debian ISOs should be EFI-compatible by default, but with CSM enabled it's easy to select the CSM boot option instead.

Comment: So, is there a guide on how to reboot LFS (hopefully a fairly new guide) while on a Live CD?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with LFS at all. But as far as I understand it's about how you boot into Debian which you are using to work with LFS.

Answer (score 4):

Like you I'm using the USB Stick to installing Gentoo using grub-install within a chrooted environment and got the same error:

```
(chroot) > grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.

EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: 
No such file or directory.
```

From following the Gentoo handbook bootloader steps:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Bootloader

**Solution was here, lower down in the manual:**

Some motherboard manufacturers seem to only support the /efi/boot/ directory location for the .EFI file in the EFI System Partition (ESP). The GRUB installer can perform this operation automatically with the `--removable` option. Verify the ESP is mounted before running the following commands. Presuming the ESP is mounted at /boot (as suggested earlier), execute:

```
(chroot) > grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --removable
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished.  No error reported.
```

Which fixed the `EFI not supported` problem.  That suggests the source of the error is something to do with the USB stick, the motherboard's UEFI settings for the USB, and grub-install trying to do the thing in a place where no such support exists.

Telling `grub-install` we're using a USB stick with the `--removable` flag seems to correct the error.

Comment: This solution does something slightly different: It does not register Grub in the UEFI boot order. Instead, it relies on the firmware autodetecting a `bootx64.efi` file in a certain location. It’s also important to note that this may conflict with other bootloaders/boot managers.

Comment: Thank you. This actually fixed my issue by adding `--removable` flag.  Now grub works on my laptop (dual booting win and debian)